# Should I put a semicolon after property names in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, oop, formatting

What is the recommended format in object oriented MATLAB: to put a semicolon after the property names or not?

```
classdef SemicolonVersion
   properties
      prop1;
   end
end
```

OR

```
classdef NoSemicolonVersion
   properties
      prop1
   end
end
```

Comment: You can use either.  MATLAB documentation uses both so there's really no accepted way.  Use whatever you feel like. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-attributes.html

Comment: Thanks, put your comment to an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Consider it done.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either. MATLAB documentation uses both so there's really no accepted way. Use whatever you feel like.

http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-attributes.html